# How to instantiate an es6 class that has been transpiled to es5

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, es6-modules, es6-class

I am creating a module that I want to publish to NPM. The module exports a class that should be instantiated using the new keyword. I want that the package should be importable using the es5 require keyword as well es6 import keyword. I had transpiled the code to es5 for backward compatibility. When I test it out with es6 import and transpile es5, the code run as expected. However, when I test it out using the require() keyword, I get an error that the class is not a constructor. I have created sample codes to replicate the problem.

This is a sample class which I transpiled to es5 in the file index2.js

```
// classe.js

class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'name'
  }
  greet() {
    return `Hello ${this.name}`;
  }
}

export default MyClass;
```

## To test the code I created the two tests codes below

Here is the es5 implementation. I expect that since index2 is already in es5 it should run by executing `node test1`

```
// test1.js

const MyClass = require('./index2');

console.log(MyClass)

const greeter = new MyClass()
const greeting = greeter.greet();
console.log(greeting)
```

Here the es6 implementation. When I transpile this and execute as `node test2`, it produces the expected result.

```
// test2.js

import MyClass from './index2';

console.log(MyClass)

const greeter = new MyClass()
const greeting = greeter.greet();
console.log(greeting)
```

## Here is my expected result

```
[Function: MyClass]
Hello name
```

## this is the error I am getting when I run the test1.js

```
{ default: [Function: MyClass] }
/Users/godfreytutu/Desktop/classe/test1.js:5
const greeter = new MyClass()
                ^

TypeError: MyClass is not a constructor
```

Please, how should I implement it so that I can use the require keyword as well as the import keyword? Thanks.

Comment: according to your snippets, `require('./index2');` does not return `MyClass` but instead an object `{ default: MyClass }`. therefore `const MyClass = require('./index2').default;`

Comment: @Thomas it works, thanks. Like I mention I want to publish the module I am working on to NPM and would like that users can just use the require keyword without the `.default` to follow convention. How may I export the class to achieve that? Or what should I change in the implementation? I will appreciate your suggestion. Thanks once more.